# Use sp_getapplock to lock on data resources scales well?

Tags: sql-server, locking

If there is a table with several registers about several users, for example, like this:

```
create table test (id int identity, userid int, data nvarchar(max));

insert into test (userid, data)
          select 1, 'aaa'
union all select 1, 'bbb'
union all select 2, 'ccc'
union all select 3, 'ddd'
union all select 3, 'eee';
```

And several processes running the following update:

```
update test
set data = data + 'z'
where userid = 1;
```

Depending on the execution plan of the update query it is possible that one update would start updating in on direction while the other process would be updating in the opposite direction leading to a deadlock.

To prevent this, without locking the whole table, maybe one could use the `sp_getapplock` and lock on the resource `'userid_1'`. That way only one process can be updating each user, but several processes can still run side by side updating other users (`sp_getapplock` on `'userid_3'` and so on).

```
begin transaction

sp_getapplock @Resource = 'userid_1', @LockMode = 'Exclusive'; 

update test
set data = data + 'z'
where userid = 1;

sp_releaseapplock @Resource = 'userid_1';

commit transaction
```

Is `sp_getapplock` able to work like this for many users?

I ask this because the examples I found are using `sp_getapplock` to lock on application resources like `'form_1'`, and maybe that can mean the `sp_getapplock` does not need to scale to lots of resources (like 100k users with 10 locks on different users at each moment).

I will test this but would like to know if I am doing something wrong.

Note: I considered adding a `user` table just to update the user record with some dummy data in a transaction to get the same effect, but it does not sound right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "scales well". You're essentially rolling your own mutex for a logical entity in your database (in your example, a user). Calls to get the mutex after the first will block until the mutex is released (or the owning scope ends, at which point the mutex is released implicitly). This will inherently reduce concurrency, but I would argue that that's what you're *trying to do*. But to answer your question about resource usage, app locks utilize the same infrastructure that is used to lock, say, a table or a data page. The only difference is that you're controlling it explicitly.